# How to create local notification ios

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

```
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotificationalloc] init]; 
localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

I'm not receiving local notification,can anyone say how to get local notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];

Try this!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the time when to fire notification. You have just created notification but not set when it need to be fired.

For example..

localNotif.fireDate = [itemDate dateByAddingTimeIntervalInterval:-(minutesBefore*60)];

Answer (score 0):

If application is foreground stage then you wan't seen those notification. you should have to code on delegate method.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UILocalNotification *notif = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
            notif.alertBody = @"Your Session is Ready";
            notif.alertAction = @"Take Now";
            notif.soundName = @"DingBell.wav";
            [notif setFireDate:[gregCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];
            notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
            [notif setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
            NSMutableDictionary *userDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [userDict setValue:self.stringModuleID forKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey"];
            [userDict setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"alarm%d",[[setreminingDay objectAtIndex:i] intValue]] forKey:@"alarm"];
            notif.userInfo = userDict;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```